# how to persist data when user session end

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

currently i working on a system with login module,
when a user logged in, a session store information about him will be created.
when session end and user does not check remember me option, page will be redirect to login page with a return URL.
now there is a problem.....
after session expired, and user logged in again,
how can i get back the data in previous page?

i know there is a view state, but all session expired how i store it to session...?
currently i just store them in cookie.

is there any better solution i can do to perform this task?

Comment: May be you can cache those details for specific time and can access after login.

Comment: how should i cache the data?

Comment: http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/12/10/c-cache-helper-class/ Provides you well defined explanation for how you can use cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass return url in query string.

```
Response.Redirect("/Account/Login?redirect=/Home/Dashboard");
```

**Edit**

If you are using ASP.NET Web Forms, then you can use *ViewState* to save form state. Or alternatively, you can use *cookies*. But cookies have it's limitations in size.

Another way is also to save data in [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: What do you mean by  *fresh new page*?

Comment: mean, i fill up a form in a page, then i go out for lunch, after 1hour i back, the session expired, redirect me to login page, after login, i return to the form page with all blank.....